# SQL Server 2014 Migration

Tags: sql-server-2014

Recently we've been looking into upgrading our SQL Server 2008 Instances to 2014.

As part of this we also need to complete a hardware migration and so we're going down the backup/restore route.

We've completed a migration in our UAT environment and this has led to a few performance concerns with key business logic queries. To mitigate these we've updated stats across the board but the execution however we're still seeing the issue.

My question is - are there any benefits to rebuilding the indexes on our tables to resolve this or would that be a waste of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup and restoring a database will leave any indexes in the same state as they were prior to your move. Rebuilding them will only help if they are a) fragmented and b) truly the cause of the slowdown you are seeing, but its more likely that your new hardware or sql configuration (if they are different to how they were previously) are the root cause if this is new once the database has been moved.

Unfortunately there are a number of variables that could have caused what you are seeing. Have you profiled the query that is executing slowly and compared to a plan on the old server? Have you then checked you have the correct indexes in place for your query? How is your new hardware / disk array configured? Where are your (new) master and temp db's located?

[This](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/03/sql-server-2005-setup-checklist-part-2-after-the-install/) guide (although a bit outdated) should give you some starting points to check your new server is configured correctly.

Comment: We've been running an the original 2008 db in parallel. The plans for the query are dramatically different despite the data being identical. In the query the predicate column is indexed however on 2014 the index is not being used,resulting in poor performance